# cannot resolve encodetoString

Tags: java, android

**i cannot resolve encodeToString() for base64.
i tried import android.util.Base64 but still it doesnt work
it also show error in Base64.DEFAULT and still i tried Base64.NO_WRAP and is also did not work**

```
 public String convertBmToStr(Bitmap bmp) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream strm = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, strm); //compress to which format you want.
    byte[] byte_arr = strm.toByteArray(); //byte array of image
    String imagetoStr = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT);
    return imagetoStr;
}
```

Comment: Should work if you have `import android.util.Base64;`, but why don't you try showing us the full real error message you get, so we can see what you see. I.e. *show* us the error, don't explain/interpret it, because you're probably doing that wrong, if you still get the error with the `import` you *explained* you tried.

Answer (score 0):

A data URI follows a certain scheme:

```
data:[<media type>][;base64],<data>
```

You need to manually add the prefix:

```
String imagetoStr = "data:image/png;base64," + Base64.encodeToString(
                        byte_arr, Base64.NO_WRAP);
```